# using a pointer to a value type in a Dictionary value

Tags: .net, vb.net, pointers

This small snippet of code is to increment a count value (integer) which is stored in a dictionary using my referenced object as a key. When the dictionary is small, multiple lookups aren't a big deal but this particular dictionary can get quite large.

```
Private RefCount As IDictionary(Of ILifeTimeManaged, Integer)
......... CODE HERE.....

Private Sub IncrementRefCount(ByVal entity As ILifeTimeManaged)

    Dim prevCount As Integer

    ''# if we have no reference entry, add one and set its count to 1

    If Not RefCount.TryGetValue(entity, prevCount) Then
        RefCount.Add(entity, 1)
    Else
        ''# otherwise increment its count by 1

        RefCount.Item(entity) = prevCount + 1
    End If

End Sub
```

I find a corresponding dictionary entry then increment the int stored in the value, or add a new dictionary entry.

Is it a bad idea to use a pointer to the dictionary value? Then I can avoid the second key lookup when I already have gotten the value. How would you implement it? Is this even possible in .NET4?

Can I do it using IntPtr do you think?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx

```
RefCount.Item(entity) = prevCount + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make a pointer to any given type in VB like you could in C++.  However, you can wrap a value type in a reference type to get the semantics you want.

```
Public Class Ref(Of T As Structure)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal value As T)
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub

    Public Property Value As T

End Class
```

This lets you return a "pointer" to an integer (more correctly, a reference to something containing an integer).  You could then write something like this:

```
Private RefCount As IDictionary(Of ILifeTimeManaged, Ref(Of Integer))
......... CODE HERE.....

Private Sub IncrementRefCount(ByVal entity As ILifeTimeManaged)
    Dim count As Integer

    ''# if we have no reference entry, add one and set its count to 1
    If Not RefCount.TryGetValue(entity, count) Then
        RefCount.Add(entity, New Ref(Of Integer)(1))
    Else
        ''# otherwise increment its count by 1
        count.Value += 1
    End If
End Sub
```

You could add some conversion methods between `T` and `Ref(Of T)` to the `Ref` class to possibly simplify the syntax (like in the Add call).  In my opinion, doing so would give you something closer to C++ references than C++ pointers.  Whether that's what you want or not is up to you.

**Edit RE your Edit:** IntPtr is designed to represent any pointer type in interop code calls.  Perhaps a better name would have been NativePtr.  There is no way to use an IntPtr in managed code the way I think you want, as you would a pointer in C++.

Comment: Right but here I weigh the cost of unboxing versus the cost of my Dictionary lookup.

Comment: To clarify: I'm talking about the "unboxing" of the container to derive my int, if I use a reference object to hold one.

Comment: @Matthew PK: You have the "unboxing" of the Ref vs the "unboxing" of the Dictionary and the lookup, so it *should* be a win for the Ref in this function, but this is definitely a micro-optimization.

Answer (score 2):

That does not look like a bad idea.

If you want to improve performance, you may want to add a property RefCount to the ILifeTimeManaged interface and use it instead of using the dictionary. But I don't know your design and goal, so can't say is this apropriate to you.

Comment: The ILifeTimeManaged cannot store the reference count. ILikeTimeManaged objects are managed by a LifeTimeManager which basically keeps track of how many instances are outstanding and handling the creation or destruction of them.

Comment: Ok. Btw, you realize that in .NET you don't actually need to count references, because GC do all the work with memory management?

Comment: Not in my case. The manager handles the disposing of all of its objects and decides whether to reissue them. You're gonna have to trust me on my implementation here ;)

Comment: Can't add comments anywhere... If you are using generic Dictionary<ILifeTimeManaged, int> then you will have no boxing/unboxing operations

Comment: I assume you're talking about my comment to the other answer... if I create an reference object to hold an int value, I will be "unboxing" the reference object to derive my integer.

Comment: Boxing and unboxing will not happen if you using generic dictionary (and you are using it). Just look into the source code of Dictionary class (or what implementation of generic IDictionary you are using) and you'll see that Object type is not used to store values. Intead of Object TValue is used. So there is no boxing and unboxing performed. Also you'll find there a private class Entry which is used to hold values (some kind analogue of Ref class which was proposed in other comment).

Comment: You're not following me. Don't get hung up on the term "unboxing". I'm saying that if I store an object with an int property (rather than just an int) then I incur some overhead with retrieving the int property. This is pursuant to Gideon's answer, where he suggests that I can use a custom class to hold my int.